# Ranking sometimes fails when int and long have the same width in C

Tags: c, 32bit-64bit

Let platform 1 have the width of `int` 4 bytes and the width of `long` 8 bytes.

Let platform 2 have the width of `int` 4 bytes and the width of `long` be the same as the width of `int`.

Then given:

```
unsigned int x = 2;
long signed int y = 3;
func(x * y);
```

When ran on platform 1, the effective type of the first argument of `func` is `long signed int`. This is as expected. It follows § 6.3.1.1.1.4 that the `unsigned int` type has the same rank as `signed int`. It also then follows that `signed int` type has a lower rank than `long signed int` according to § 6.3.1.1.1.3. This then triggers the result of the multiplication to be converted to `long signed int` type, following § 6.3.1.8.1.4.4. Great!

When ran on platform 2, the result of the multiplication is `long unsigned int`. **Why?**

---

**Background**

Section § 6.3.1.1, subsection 1, point 3 in the C99 standard says:

> The rank for `long long int` shall be greater than the rank of `long int`,
> which shall be greater than the rank of `int`, which shall be greater
> that the rank of `short int`, which shall be greater than the rank of
> `signed char`.

One thing this suggests is that `long int` has a higher rank than `int`.

Also, point 4 in the same paragraph in the C99 standard says:

> The rank of any `unsigned` integer type shall equal the rank of the
> corresponding `signed` integer type, if any.

A couple of things from here are that the `unsigned int` type has the same rank as the `signed int` type. Similarly, the `long unsigned int` type has the same rank as `long signed int`.

Lastly, in section § 6.3.1.8, subsection 1, point 4.3 says:

> Otherwise, if the operand that has unsigned integer type has rank
> greater or equal to the rank of the type of the other operand, then
> the operand with signed integer type is converted to the type of the
> operand with unsigned integer type.

And point 4.4:

> Otherwise, if the type of the operand with signed integer type can
> represent all values of the type of the operand with unsigned integer
> type, then the operand with unsigned integer type is converted to the
> type of the operand with signed integer type.

---

**Test code**

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define func(x) _Generic((x), long unsigned int: func_longunsignedint, long signed int: func_longsignedint, signed int: func_signedint, unsigned int: func_unsignedint)(x);

void func_longunsignedint (long unsigned int x)
{
    printf("%s\t%lu\n", __func__, x);
}

void func_longsignedint (long signed int x)
{
    printf("%s\t%ld\n", __func__, x);
}

void func_signedint (signed int x)
{
    printf("%s\t%d\n", __func__, x);
}

void func_unsignedint (unsigned int x)
{
    printf("%s\t%u\n", __func__, x);
}

int main(void)
{
    printf("int width %d\n", sizeof(int));
    printf("long width %d\n", sizeof(long));
    unsigned int x = 2;
    long signed int y = -3;
    func(x * y);
}
```

For platform 1, compile with `gcc -m64` to hopefully force long to the 8 bytes and int be 4 bytes.

For platform 2, compile with `gcc -m32` to hopefully force long to the 4 bytes and int be 4 bytes.

Comment: Aaaand a [gobolt link](https://godbolt.org/z/f4x3Ks)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We take `unsigned` and `long signed int` and follow [C11 6.3.1.8](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.1.8):

> - Otherwise, if the type of the operand with signed integer type can represent all of the values of the type of the operand with unsigned
>   integer type, then the operand with unsigned integer type is converted
>   to the type of the operand with signed integer type.

On 64-bit platform #1 type `long signed int` can represent all values of `unsigned`, because it has 64 bits vs `unsigned` has 32bits. So the `unsigned` is converted to `long signed int`.

On 32-bit platform #2 type `long signed int` can't represent all values of `unsigned` (`UINT_MAX=2^32` but `LONG_MAX=2^31-1`). So we continue...

> - Otherwise, both operands are converted to the unsigned integer type corresponding to the type of the operand with signed integer type.

...so on platform #2 the "unsigned integer type corresponding to the type of signed integer type" - this is `long signed int` + `unsigned` = `long unsigned int`. So on platform #2 both operands are converted to `long unsigned int`, thus the result your are seeing.

Comment: The bit I missed is that `long signed int can't represent all values of unsigned` on platform 2. Great answer!